# centering images in horizontal list

Tags: html, css, html-lists, image

I have a horizontal list used as a nav, where I want to put images/icons above the text in the list.

However, I can't get the images to center with each list item.

The images has the exact same size.

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">

<ul>
    <li><img src="images/kranznav.png" alt="kranz" /><a href="index.php">COMPETE</a></li>
    <li><img src="images/thumbnav.png" alt="thumb" /><a href="index.php">SCORE</a></li>
    <li><img src="images/bagnav.png" alt="bag" /><a href="index.php">SHOP</a></li>
    <li><img src="images/morenav.png" alt="more" /><a href="index.php">MORE</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="clear">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav {
    background:#ffffff;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:-2em;

}


#nav ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}

#nav li {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    width:2%;
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-right:10%;
    margin-top:5%;
}

#nav a {
    display:block;
    width:20%;
    margin-right:0% auto;
    padding-left:0% auto;
    color:#5E09CB;
    text-decoration:none;

}
```

Comment: I believe li is not wide enough for image to center. try increasing width and reducing margins on `#nav li` Have a look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fLaBz/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `text-align:center;` to `#nav li`

Comment: Could it be the text that's off?

Comment: ! please test before post!1!!

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is the width of 2% you gave the list items.
This limits the width

http://jsfiddle.net/bukfixart/Z9uc7/

Try it this way:

```
#nav li {
display:inline;
float:left;
/*width:2%;*/
margin-left:10%;
margin-right:10%;
margin-top:5%;

text-align:center;
}
```